# Retrieving of ip:port between 2 APIs with Express/NestJS

Tags: node.js, api, networking, nestjs

I'm currently stuck with a logical problem.

I have 2 api:

**http://localhost:8082/items/4** => returns a list of items

**http://localhost:8084/get/1** => returns a object and a list of items from 8082

```
this.httpService.get('http://localhost:8082/items/4'); // into method of http://localhost:8084/get/1
```

When i reach the http://localhost:8084/get/1 via Google Chrome, my port into the 8082 instance is displayed as google chrome port eg: 51977 and not 8084. I'm not supposed to get 8084 ?

(req.connection.remotePort from express)

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kdmt2.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

That port must be busy:
1: Try restarting your system
2: Or kill the process that is using it